# Неправильно работают хлебные крошки (breadcrumbs) на сайте

Tags: seo, opencart, schema.org, breadcrumbs

Здравствуйте. Настроил вручную хлебные крошки для сайта на CMS Opencart, но в поисковиках они выглядят не так как хотелось бы.

Вот, например, как выглядит страница в Яндексе:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Слово **tutorial** взято из url страницы, а не из названия как должно было.
А вот как в гугле:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу, чтобы было так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На валидаторах никаких ошибок не обнаружено.

Вот код:

```
<ul class="breadcrumb" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem">
        <a itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Thing" itemprop="item" href="https://домен.me/"><span itemprop="name"><img src="image/home.png"></span></a><meta itemprop="position" content="1">
    </li>
    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem">
        <a itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Thing" itemprop="item" href="https://домен.me/tutorial"><span itemprop="name">Название страницы</span></a><meta itemprop="position" content="2">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Нет никакой гарантии, что поисковики будут хватать и выводить хлебные крошки — хотят обрабатывают, хотят - нет
2. По общим впечатлениям все нормально, тест валидатора проходит (https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/) но главная, обычно, не размечается — https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList

Comment: Спасибо. О главной знаю, у меня там изображение домика просто на сайте. Мне нужно чтобы название страницы выводилось на русском. Такое заметил у многих с использованием микроразметки от http://data-vocabulary.org/ но как говорится у них на официальном сайте, нужно использовать schema.org. Что скажете?

Comment: 1. Но у Вас главная все равно размечена. Во многих плагинах она вообще генерируется отдельно и можно прописать внешний вид отдельно
2. Поисковики обрабатывают все микроразметки, просто они рекомендуют schema.org, т.к. они ее постоянно развивают. Главное - что-бы не было конфликта разных между собой на одной странице и периодически проверять правильность. К примеру, около полугода назад обновили требования к schema

Comment: понял, спасибо!

Comment: Здравствуйте. Получилось так как я хотел. Все таки нужно было использовать микроразметку от data-vocabulary.org. Возможно еще не работало из за того, что была размечена главная, а текста там не было, был img домика. Еще раз спасибо за советы!